# How can I create targets in nx proejct,json with different executors - package and webpack-browser

Tags: angular, angular-module-federation, nx-monorepo

I am using nx based angular project to publish my angular MFEs as npm packages. I am using build task as follows

```
"build": {
  "executor": "@nx/angular:package",
  "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/dist/{projectRoot}"],
  "options": {
    "project": "projects/activity/ng-package.json",
    "updateBuildableProjectDepsInPackageJson": true
  }
```

}

I want to add one more target in proejct.json file of each MFE to publish it using module federation as well. I plan to use "executor": "@nx/angular:webpack-browser".
Is it doable? please guide how